# Laptop Fans always at 0RPM

Tags: laptop, asus, fancontrol

After my fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04, I could feel heat from my laptop. Turned out that fans are not running.

Specs:

- Asus TUF FX504
- i7 8750H
- nVidia 1050Ti

[image: Fan speed info]

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/301745). Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to make it look nice.

Comment: Do you know if the problem is specific to Ubuntu? Do the fans work in Windows or other OS's?

Comment: those temps look pretty normal for a laptop.  Push it to 70C and see if it still says the fan is not running, and feel for airflow at that temp.

Comment: @NerdOfLinux The fan work perfectly fine in windows

Comment: The temps look fine. Worry a lot if they approach 100C. Install `thermald` if you'd like to assure some cooling control.

Answer (score 0):

For my laptop, Asus TUF helped Asus fan control: https://github.com/dominiksalvet/asus-fan-control